# Why won't the Capture One Color Editor expand?

Tags: software, sony, capture-one

I am using Capture One Pro for Sony 11.01 on a Win 10 PC. I am working with RAW files captured with a Sony Alpha 6000. No setting changes were made.

When I try to expand the color editor tool, nothing happens, the tool doesn't open. When I try to add it as a floating module it will appear, but with no active options. No error messages are thrown.

All other tools are working.

Why is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: You have selected a photo, right? Because the tool will "disappear" as soon as no photo is selected. Also, you have expanded the tool? There's a small arrow next to its name. Also, you have tried to reset C1's layout via `WIndow`-`Workspace`-`Default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Capture One has a minimum screen height of 800px.  If there is not enough space Color editor cannot expand.  To fix the problem you can do one of several things:
>
> - Set your screen resolution to at least 800px in height, set text
>   scaling to 100%.
> - Drag the color editor tool so it is floating on screen.
> - **Remove extra tools from the color tab to give color editor more space.**

The latter worked for me. Why the tools were inactive when the tool was floating I can't say, it now works.

Comment: Would you mind to add the source of your solution? I really cannot find any information about it, and IMHO, one should always cite one's sources. Or did you come up with that information yourself?

Comment: Floated tool and can now expand the editor....but there is no colour showing in the colour wheel........

Comment: @AKamera have you selected a photo? A little more info would be nice - also, I'm not sure if this belongs here, as "Color editor does not show colors" is a different problem than "Color editor does not expand". Maybe it would be best to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a pain in the ass. However, there is a simple solution. Create a custom tab JUST for the color editor.

- Right-click on the tabs bar
- Select **Add Tool Tab**
- Pick **Custom**
- Name it what you want
- Click on the tab you just created
- Right-click anywhere in the free space of the tab
- Select **Add Tool**
- Pick **Color Editor** from the drop menu
- All done!